# Django, how to get attribute of forignkey related object

Tags: django

I have below models,

```
class Model_1(models.Model)
     price = models.IntergerField()

class Model_2(models.Model)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Model_1)
    quantity = models.IntergerField()
   
    @property
    def totalprice(self):
        return self.quantity * self.product__price
```

`arr = [obj1,obj2,obj3]`  # objects of Model_2

**I am getting error that arr objects has no attribute 'product__price'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access the attributes of the related `product`:

```
class Model_2(models.Model)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Model_1)
    quantity = models.IntergerField()
   
    @property
    def totalprice(self):
        return self.quantity * self.product.price
```

A `ForeignKey` lazily loads the related object, so if you fetch `self.product`, it will make a query, and load the related `Model_1` object in memory, you can then access the attributes of that object.